# Como puedo eliminar parentesis dentro de una variable con replace() de javascript

Tags: javascript

Lo que quiero saber es como puedo eliminar paréntesis de un string con el metodo replace() de js.
el caso es que tengo una cadena de texto de la cual quiero eliminar cierto texto que contiene paréntesis en el en diversas ocaciones sin embargo solo me elimina el primero y eh intentado utilizar la forma replace(regexp, newSubStr, flag) pero no me da ningun resultado.

Adjunto un ejemplo de lo que tengo hasta ahorita:

```js
var text = 'texto sin parentesis, texto con (parentesis), otro texto con (parentesis)';
    var replaceString = 'con (parentesis)';
    console.log(text.replace(replaceString, ''));
```

agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = 'texto sin parentesis, texto con (parentesis), otro texto con (parentesis)';
var replaceString = 'con \\(parentesis\\)';

console.log(text.replace(new RegExp(replaceString, 'g'), ''));
```

Se deben realizar unas pequeñas modificaciones a tu `replaceString`, puesto que al parecer los parentesis son caracteres especiales interpretados por las expresiones regulares, por lo cual deben ser escapados, la manera de escapar un `\` es con otro `\`, por lo cual tu `RegExp` queda así:

```
var replaceString = 'con \\(parentesis\\)';
```

Y en esta parte:

```
console.log(text.replace(new RegExp(replaceString, 'g'), ''));
```

Creamos un regex apartir de la variable `replaceString` y le añadimos el flag `g` para hacer que todos los casos sean tomados en cuenta.

Comment: Entiendo eso sin embargo no puedo ingresar los valores manualmente los valores están definidos en una variable como se muestra en mi ejemplo.
lo que necesito es saber si existe alguna forma de sustituir de la cadena de texto el valor dentro de la variable replaceString

Comment: Ah osea quieres reemplazar con (parentesis), por una cadena vacia cierto??

Comment: exactamente eso mismo

Comment: Listo respuesta editada, creo que ahora es lo que deseas.

Answer (score 0):

La función `replace` también puede tomar por parámetro una expresión regular.

```
// Ponemos el flag g para que remplace todas
// las ocurrencias
// Y debemos escapar los caracteres ) y (
const regex = /con \(parentesis\)/g;

const rep = text.replace(regex, '');
console.log(rep);
// texto sin parentesis, texto , otro texto
```

Espero que sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con el siguiente código

```js
var texto = 'texto sin parentesis, texto con (parentesis), otro texto con (parentesis)';
var textoSinParentesis = texto.replace(/\((\w+)\)/g, "$1");
console.log(textoSinParentesis);
```

Cuando en una expresión regular se utilizan paréntesis, se crea y guarda una referencia al texto con el que coincidió. Podemos reutilizar esa referencia usando `$1`.

Para entender mejor el uso de esas referencias puedes leer un poco al respecto aquí [Regex con paréntsis](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Usando_par%C3%A9ntesis)